# Access variables inside constructor outside of it in Ionic Local Notifications

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, localnotification

```
export class HomePage 
{

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, private plt: Platform, public localNotifications: LocalNotifications,) {
     this.plt.ready().then((rdy) => {

       let date = new Date();
       let before_work_notification_time = new Date(date.setHours(7,0,0) )


       this.localNotifications.schedule({
         id:1,
         title: 'Good morning',
         text: 'My morning notification' + before_work_notification_time.getHours(),
         at: before_work_notification_time,
         every: 'day',
         data: { mydata: 'My daily before work notification'}
       });
}
}
```

I would like access the value of "work_start_notification_time" outside of constructor in "ionViewDidLoad()". Is it possible to do? i am trying to come up with a graph of all notification times I have created. Or, is it possible to access the localnotification I created using it's "id"?

Thanks in advance,
skr

Answer (score 1):

```
export class HomePage 
{

//outside scope variables
public work_start_notification_time:any ;

 constructor() {
    //assign a value 
this.work_start_notification_time = "somevalue";

}

someMethod()
{
  //access from outside constructor 

console.log(this.work_start_notification_time);
}
}
```